# Traversing arrays php

Tags: php, arrays, search, loops

I was wondering if there is a better solution to loop through an array from mid to end then from start to mid. Particularly for an associative array.

So for example if there is an associative array with the keys

```
$dow = array(Mon => etc, Tue => etc, Wed  => etc, Thr  => etc .. to .. Sun  => etc).
```

I would start searching the array from Thurs to find the next day with something specific which could be anyday but happens to be on Tues, I usually iterate from Thurs (by index) to Sunday then, reset and start again from Monday to Wed and find the target when reaching Tues.

I count the index via an id and when it reaches 6 reset the id to 0

```
 $id = 3 // Found day is Thursday id

//Loop function starts here   
$id++; // start search from one day above found day
 if ($id >= 6){ //when reaching Sunday
    $id = 0 // start search from monday
  }  
// check array here for that specific thing
```

So the question is to ask if there is a more simple solution than this, ie split array from index thursday to sunday and add it onto the beginning of the array and then do the loop without having to count an index or if there are any other solutions without using the count index.

Comment: Why do you need to start iterating from thursday, specifically (or any other day for that matter), rather than from the array's beginning?

Comment: There is no any complex logic behind it and you're doing simple and no problem with it. By the way you have to write array `key` and `value` (string values) in `Quotes`

Comment: there's no problem in your implementation

Comment: Same as SIT LCU, Why not just iterate the whole array.

Comment: What is your PHP version?

Comment: Why are you iterating days of week (instead of, well, dates)? That's seems kinda wrong approach to me. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: At ST LCU ..the reason is I am searching a rota for available days, so I am looking for the next available day after Thursday which would be on Tuesday, so the logic is to check if Fri is avail, which is not, then Sat etc reaching Sun then starting again from Monday until I reach Tues which is a yes. (Php 5+) I guess counting an id is the best bet. Just thought there was a solution with the various array function PHP provides. I thought I was being amateurish with this approach. Still learning much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with [**array_splice**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php):

```
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);

$lastDays = array_splice($array, 3);
$firstDays = $array;

print_r(array('first days' => $firstDays, 'last days' => $lastDays));
```

If the day is not in `$lastDays` (use a boolean like `$matchFound`) then you would search in `$firstDays`.

Or just use with [**array_merge**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php):

```
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);

$array = array_merge(array_splice($array, 3), $array);
print_r($array);
```

where output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 6
    [3] => 7
    [4] => 1
    [5] => 2
    [6] => 3
)
```

and then you can search with a `foreach`.

Comment: Thank you, I like this approach as it takes out the any id checking/amends out of the loop. Which means I can keep the function simple and put any array into the search. It makes it more simple to read. At least for me :)

Answer (score 0):

maybe a foreach would be more efficient. hope this helps.

```
$id = 3 // Found day is Thursday id
$i =0;
//Loop function starts here   
foreach($dow as $idx)
   if($id == $i):

   else if($i > $id):


   endif;

   if($i == count($dow)){$i=0;}else{$i++;}
endforeach;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I got a nice approach using array splice and merge, that way I can keep any if else out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    $dow = array("mon","tue","wed","thu","fri","sat","sun");

    $pick_a_day = 2; // user input; NON zero based. monday = 1
    $pick_a_day--; // make it zero based to use in code

    foreach($dow as $inc => $an_element )
    {
        echo $dow[($pick_a_day+(count($dow))) % (count($dow))]." - loop number:".($inc+1)."\n";
        $pick_a_day++;
    }

?>
```

output

```
tue - loop number:1
wed - loop number:2
thu - loop number:3
fri - loop number:4
sat - loop number:5
sun - loop number:6
mon - loop number:7
```

Comment: nitpicking, but `--$pick_a_day` is more efficient than `$pick_a_day--`. The same goes for the increment inside the foreach.

Comment: @STTLCU oh...?? Well this is immediately ["OCD"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obsessive%E2%80%93compulsive_disorder) approved. thanks for adding one more bother to my programming style! hehe!  _(continues the writing of really dirty code but bothers about variable casting efficiency)_

Comment: hey, i specified it was just nitpicking :D

Comment: Thank you, this works well but want to keep the foreach loop basic and put the logic outside of the foreach loop. That way its simple for me to read as a newbie. Got the answer with array_splice and merge.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best solution, but a solution:

```
function half($array) {
    $h = sizeof($array) / 2;
    $a1 = array_splice($array, $h);
    $a2 = array_splice($array, 0);
    $res = array_merge($a1, $a2);
    return $res;
}

$dow = array('Mon' => 'etc1', 'Tue' => 'etc2', 'Wed'  => 'etc3', 'Thr'  => 'etc4', 'Fri' => 'etc5', 'Sat' => 'etc6', 'Sun' => 'etc7');

$b = half($dow);
```

Now you can go through with a foreach, or how would you like. Result of $b:

```
Array
(
    [Thr] => etc4
    [Fri] => etc5
    [Sat] => etc6
    [Sun] => etc7
    [Mon] => etc1
    [Tue] => etc2
    [Wed] => etc3
)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for but got the answer already above. Much appreciated :)